# Why is Log Analytics count() function reporting fewer records than count operator?

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics

I have the following query running in Log Analytics to count the (very large, into the millions!) number of exceptions that are being raised by my app:

```
exceptions
| where problemId has "KeyNotFoundException"
| count
```

however, if I change this to

```
exceptions
| where problemId has "KeyNotFoundException"
| summarize count()
```

the resulting count goes **down**, even though these exceptions are being created almost constantly (i.e the count going up would be explainable).

I can't find anything online about whether/why there is a difference between `count` and `count()`, other than the obvious difference that `count` is an operator on a set of records and `count()` is an aggregation function which must be run within a `summarize` context.

Can anyone explain the difference between the two approaches. Is `summarize` somehow working on an out-of-date set of records?

Comment: Is there a chance that the period filtering in the GUI is different?

Comment: Oh, good call! I was using the default time range of "Last 24 hours", which obviously has the potential to lose more "early" records than are being added. Specifying an explicit "since midnight" time range in the query yields the behaviour I'm expecting.

If you put your suggestion as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

- As suggested by [David דודו Markovitz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6336479/david-%d7%93%d7%95%d7%93%d7%95-markovitz) and as mentioned by [Rob Gilliam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23408/rob-gilliam) that issue got resolved. Posting the research over here to help the other community members who have similar kinds of issues.
- When we are trying to check any query in KQL, we should remember that the default time range will be set to 24 hours, and we can change that according to our requirement to get accurate data.

[image]